# Sort Divs Via Multiple Drop Down Menus via data-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have working code that sorts all the appropriate divs on my page via a data-eventtype attribute.

I've got a drop down menu that you can select your attribute from and the divs sort to only show those whose data-eventtype matches the attribute you choose. The code hides the other divs that don't match.

Working example using one attribute drop down:

https://codepen.io/btissame-qorchi/pen/zYGKEgb

I need to allow the user to select multiple attributes via multiple drop downs and have the results filtered further by each selection.
So you could select "Music" from the first drop down menu and see all music entries, but then further filter the results via "1920s from a second drop down menu. Or "Art" from the first drop down and "1850s" from the second.

My JS:

```
$( ".event-type-select" ).change(function() {
  var selectedEventType = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedEventType == "all") {
    $('.container .div').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('.container div').addClass('hidden');
    $('.container div[data-eventculture="' + selectedEventType + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.container div[data-eventdate="' + selectedEventType + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
  } 
});
```

My HTML code with multiple attributes:

```
    <form>
    <select class="event-type-culture">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="music">Music</option>
      <option value="art">Art</option>
      <option value="fashion">Fashion</option>
    </select>

   <select class="event-type-date">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="1850s">1850s</option>
      <option value="1920s">1920s</option>
      <option value="1950s">1950s</option>
    </select>
    </form>

<button class="sort-button" onclick="clearFilters(); return false;" >Clear Filters</button>


    <div class="container">
      <div data-eventculture="music" data-eventdate="1850s">Music 1850s 1</div>
      <div data-eventculture="art" data-eventdate="1850s">Art 1850s 1</div>
      <div data-eventculture="fashion" data-eventdate="1850s">Fashion 1850s 1</div>

      <div data-eventculture="music" data-eventdate="1850s">Music 1850s 2</div>
      <div data-eventculture="art" data-eventdate="1850s">Art 1850s 2</div>
      <div data-eventculture="fashion" data-eventdate="1850s">Fashion 1850s 2</div>

      <div data-eventculture="music" data-eventdate="1920s">Music 1920s 1</div>
      <div data-eventculture="art" data-eventdate="1920s">Art 1920s 1</div>
      <div data-eventculture="fashion" data-eventdatee="1920s">Fashion 1920s 1</div>

      <div data-eventculture="music" data-eventdate="1920s">Music 1920s 2</div>
      <div data-eventculture="art" data-eventdate="1920s">Art 1920s 2</div>
      <div data-eventculture="fashion" data-eventdate="1920s">Fashion 1920s 2</div>

      <div data-eventculture="music" data-eventdate="1950s">Music 1950s 1</div>
      <div data-eventculture="art" data-eventdate="1950s">Art 1950s 1</div>
      <div data-eventculture="fashion" data-eventdate="1950s">Fashion 1950s 1</div>

      <div data-eventculture="music" data-eventdate="1950s">Music 1950s 2</div>
      <div data-eventculture="art" data-eventdate="1950s">Art 1950s 2</div>
      <div data-eventculture="fashion" data-eventdate="1950s">Fashion 1950s 2</div>
    </div
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're duplicating `data-eventtype` for each entry, first, change the data name for the second option.

Comment: Hey Triby, I think I understand what you meant. I changed each selector to have its own unique event type name. My post has been edited to reflect the changes I've made.

Comment: `<div data-eventtype="music" data-eventtype="1850s">Music 1850s 1</div>` should be something like `<div data-eventtype="music" data-eventdate="1850s">Music 1850s 1</div>`, so, no same data name.

Comment: Yes, this is halfway towards working now! The only hiccup I run into is that switching one category back to "all" removes the .hidden class from every div, displaying divs that don't meet the first type criteria. I updated my code above to what I have now!

Comment: I added a button that clears all selections, but I am still having trouble with the category drop downs only sorting based on their own selection, and not account for any previous drop down selections. But, I am much closer than I was earlier today! Thanks for your help Triby, I really appreciate it!